# Turn Volume All The Way Up While Playing Sound Android

Tags: java, android, sdk

I would like to make the volume on the Android phone go all the way up while playing a sound. I am using `MediaPlayer` and `start()` if that helps.

Comment: That would violate the user.  They set the volume at a certain value, and they probably want to keep it that way.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html. Check setVolume(float,float);

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an app to detect slip&drop of a person.
When the slip or drop happens, the app needs to turn the volume all the way up while play a sound for some period of time.

Even it violates the user, i think it is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late, but this should do the trick:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
```

If you want to set the volume back to its original value after you're done playing your sound, have a look at this post: [Android: how to play music at maximum possible volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599259/android-how-to-play-music-at-maximum-possible-volume)