# How can I increase the maximum ringtone value?

Tags: android

I use the [`Ringtone` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html) to play an alarm when some events occur in an application I'm writing.

Everything works perfectly but for the issue that even if I set the volume to maximum (from the phone interface) it is still a little too low. Can I programmatically set a louder volume?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599259/android-how-to-play-music-at-maximum-possible-volume can be a dupllicate

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599259/android-how-to-play-music-at-maximum-possible-volume

Comment: Actually I did a search before I posted my question but I thought that android manages ringtones and music in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) Class:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: I see that `AudioManager` has different streams and that `STREAM_MUSIC` is among the ones with the highest maximum volume.
Does it mean that if I set my `Ringtone` to play on a `STREAM_MUSIC` it is the loudest I can make it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet, using `AudioManager`:

```
AudioManager am = 
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamVolume(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
    0);
```

This sets the volume to the maximum level (getStreamMaxVolume()) for the STREAM_MUSIC (which is on example a song played). For other types of sounds, use different value, like STREAM_RING etc.