# Unity3D: is it possible to check the volume of both Android and iPhone devices?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following code:

```
void Update(){
    GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ().text = AudioListener.volume.ToString();
}
```

After pushing to my Android device, it always says "1" when I push the physical volume buttons of the Android. So it is not detecting what the volume of the phone actually is. Is it possible to check the current volume of the phone?

I'm working with the Google Cardboard SDK. Maybe that's important as it uses several cameras at the same time. Maybe is it something related with permissions?

Comment: (Note: AudioListener.volume is totally unrelated.  It's just setting the volume Unity plays that item at, just like setting the volume on AudioSource.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the record,

It's a great question, can you get the **phone volume setting**, from Unity?

**Firstly**: do note that `AudioListener.volume` is totally unrelated.  That is simply the volume as Unity thinks of it for your playing music or sound effects.

**Secondly**: I'm afraid to say, I'm fairly sure there ***is no way*** to get the **phone volume setting**, from Unity, as of 2016.

If someone knows better - answer!

Nice question.

---

**UPDATE** (from comments)

Note. It is ***possibly*** possible to control system volume. But OP would have to write native plugins for that.

Consider these QA:

- For Android: [How do you get/set media volume (not ringtone volume) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593552/how-do-you-get-set-media-volume-not-ringtone-volume-in-android)
- For iOS: [iOS 9: How to change volume programmatically without showing system sound bar popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po)

**Note however** that changing the volume in iOS (nothing to do with Unity) is a tricky issue regarding *whether Apple approve it* on the app store.  Same for Android. These issues are unrelated to Unity and require knowledge about the app store, Samsung hardware, etc, in whatever year you are reading this.  AND note that in many QA about "changing volume" on phones, there is again simply confusion about changing the volume of something in an app versus "the actual phone volume control".

Comment: That's right. I think that the OP  doesn't know the difference between volume of sound/audio in Unity vs System Sound. Every volume control API     in Unity is just for the audio coming out of unity. It is possible to control system volume but he needs to write a plugin for that. For Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593552/how-do-you-get-set-media-volume-not-ringtone-volume-in-android

Comment: right.  You know, as a curiosity I wonder if that still works on Android?  (post is old).  They may have clamped down on it.  For iOS I should know but I don't.  I think they clamped down on it on iOS.

Comment: Android is almost the-same. I noticed that most things that change in Android is the graphic/ui stuff. Hardware stuff still remain the-same. I just tested it and it still work and not even deprecated. iOS is another story. Everything changes each day. The latest working code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po Not tested but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

> Evaluated difficulty level: **5/10 (Intermediate)**
> *Definitely not reccomended for a beginner*.

I will give an answer so if someone is trying this out in 2024, he will be able to make this work, **you can see the volume of the android device** *but **not only** with C#*, you need to create an AndroidClassRunner in C#, which will run an Android module (ARR) that you have created in Android Studio, as it follows:

1. [Learn how to build an ARR module (Prerequisite)](https://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u7FV-e6nUc)
2. Write the code for the AAR inside Android Studio:

   ```
    package com.yourpackage; //Write your package name (com.x.y)

    import android.app.Activity; 
    import android.content.Context; 
    import android.media.AudioManager;

    public class YourClass { //Choose a name for your class 

       private static Activity unityActivity;

       private static AudioManager audioManager;

       public static void ReceiveUnityActivity(Activity newActivity){
           unityActivity = newActivity;
       }

       public static int GetPhoneVolume(){
           if (audioManager == null)
               audioManager = (AudioManager) unityActivity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
           return audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       } 
    }
   ```
3. Export the module (follow the tutorial at step 1) and drag and drop it into Unity
4. Write the code for the ARR runner inside Unity, create a new C# class:

   ```
    public class AndroidClassRunner : MonoBehaviour
    {

       public static AndroidClassRunner SINGLETON;

       private static AndroidJavaClass unityJavaClass;
       private static AndroidJavaObject unityJavaActivity;
       private static AndroidJavaObject pluginInstanceObject;

       private void Start()
       {
           if (SINGLETON == null)
           {
               #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
                   SINGLETON = this;
                   DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
                   InitializePlugin("com.yourpackage.YourClass"); //You have to write the name of your package (com.x.y) followed by the name of your class, so it will be com.x.y.yourClassName
               #else
                   Destroy(this);
               #endif
           }
           else
               Destroy(gameObject);
       }
       private void InitializePlugin(string pluginName)
       {
           unityJavaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
           unityJavaActivity = unityJavaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
           pluginInstanceObject = new AndroidJavaObject(pluginName);

           if (pluginInstanceObject != null)
               pluginInstanceObject.CallStatic("ReceiveUnityActivity", unityJavaActivity);
           else
               Debug.LogError("Couldn't create android java plugin class!");
       }
       public static int GetPhoneVolume()
       {
           if (pluginInstanceObject != null)
               return pluginInstanceObject.CallStatic<int>("GetPhoneVolume"); //In android the value is from 0 to 15
           return -1;
       }
   }
   ```
5. And now you just have to add the MonoBehaviour to a gameobject, and the magic is done, **you can now get the phone volume**!

> You can test this out by calling from another class: `Debug.Log(AndroidClassRunner.GetPhoneVolume())`.

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone wondering.
You CAN check if the device is muted, search for it in Unity docs.
It wont really help for all cases, but in my case I had things animated according to volume. So being able to see if the device was muted, was a cool way to stop the animations and make the scene more "dynamic" per say

Comment: "search for it in Unity docs" is not a helpful answer on this website. Please reference the part and ideally quote the relevant section so your answer stays useful if unity docs are not available.