# Agora OnAudioDeviceVolumeChanged not called on android devices (unity sdk)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, agora.io

Hy all,

I have implemented OnAudioDeviceVolumeChanged call back. It works great on pc with windows but it is not called on android device. Is there a way to check when device volume is changed? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity3D: is it possible to check the volume of both Android and iPhone devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057723/unity3d-is-it-possible-to-check-the-volume-of-both-android-and-iphone-devices)

Answer (score 0):

This API is indeed only available to Windows.  The Agora team will update the documentation to reflect that.