# Unity Android Plugin-How to call onKeyDown method?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, onkeydown

i write an android library and it's extension is .jar. I want to use that in Unity.I used onKeyDown() method but when i called as an AndroidJavaObject, script isnt working. How can i call onKeyDown method in Unity?

Edit:
Unity Codes c#:

```
public AndroidJavaClass jc;
jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unitylib.unity.unitylib.StartActivity");
jc.Call ("onKeyDown");
```

Android Codes:

```
public int x = 0 ;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {

        x = 2 ;

    }
return  true;
}
```

And also i tried to start with UnityActivity but it didnt work.

Comment: You will likely not get answer if you don't provide a code

Comment: I added codes. Thanks for answer.

Comment: It's so confuse on what you are trying to achieve here. What exactly is this plugin suppose to do? `onKeyDown` function is a callback function that is called automatically...Why are you calling `onKeyDown` function directly?

Comment: I am trying to detect volume up,volume down and headsethook buttons in unity and i tried that :/ . How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `AndroidJavaClass.Call` without an object reference because it is public but not static.

So either get the object reference (the instance of your class) as a `AndroidJavaObject` and then call from that.

or a little easier, if possible make onKeyDown static, and use `AndroidJavaClass.CallStatic`

Comment: I cant make static onKeyDown it is giving error and @Programmer said onKeyDown function is a callback function in other comments. How can i detect volume up , volume down and headsethook button in unity?

Comment: In simple terms, like this: Make a plugin that listens for the event and then sends a message to unity about it. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27166551/5756888

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try that.

Comment: It works :D. I forgot to copy AndroidManifest.xml file to assets :/ Thanks for help.