# In Unity 5.6, how to get inputs in Daydream mode without installing GVR SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, google-vr, daydream

I am working on Unity 5.6.5f1 with VR enabled and Daydream selected for an Android app. So my application is working with daydream but I would like to get inputs from the Daydream remote (only a simple click). Is that possible without including the GVR sdk to my project?

Alternatively, can I catch a click on the on/off button or the sound level button of the phone in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the GVR unity package so that you can access the GVRController class. Only then can you get the on click event.

Comment: Alright, I just wanted to be sure there are no other way since I simply can't use GVR sdk because of the sdk version requirement of my project. I finally managed to use the sound up and down buttons of the remote as posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to catch clicks on the volume up and down buttons of the daydream remote control thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160114/using-volume-buttons-on-android-in-unity3d). Quite an ugly solution but it does the trick and provides two inputs.